# How to prepend an element to a Flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a flow in which I have two S3Sinks attached. In the first s3Sink, I want the file without headers and in the second s3Sink (`s3SinkHeaders`) I want the file to have headers.

```
val header = "one,two,three"
Flow[MyRegister]
    .map(mrar => mrar.toCSV + "\n")
    .map(ByteString(_))
    .alsoToMat(sinkWithHeader)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(sinkWithoutHeader)(Keep.both)
```

How can I prepend the `header` afterwards for only `sinkWithHeader` and not for `sinkWithoutHeader`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `Flow.prepend` that can be found in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6.0/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#prepend[U%3E:Out,Mat2](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[U],Mat2]):FlowOps.this.Repr[U]) ?

```scala
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

def foo[I, O, M](flow: Flow[I, O, M], head: O): Flow[I, O, M] =
  flow.prepend(Source single head)
```

Comment: .prepend(header) gives me an error of found `String` required `Graph[SourceShape[NotInferedU],NotInferedMat2]`

Comment: Anthony: prepend takes a Source, not an element.

Answer (score 0):

You need add prepend to the flow of the sink which needs header, with a source which will emit only once with the header information and then normal flow will continue.

```
  private def sinkWithHeader: Sink[ByteString, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[ByteString]
      .prepend(Source.single(ByteString("one,two,three\n")))
      .to(Sink.ignore) //write to file
  }

  private def sinkWithoutHeader: Sink[ByteString, NotUsed] = {
    Flow[ByteString]
      .to(Sink.ignore) //write to file
  }

  val header = "one,two,three"
  Flow[MyRegister]
    .map(mrar => mrar.toCSV + "\n")
    .map(ByteString(_))
    .alsoToMat(sinkWithHeader)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(sinkWithoutHeader)(Keep.both)
```

Please read here about Flow[T].prepend 
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/prepend.html